# Serverless fails to deploy locally on localstack

Tags: serverless-framework, localstack

I am trying to deploy my lambda locally using localstack but it fails because it cannot resolve variable `configFile`.

My framework version is `3`

```
service: score-api

frameworkVersion: '3'

plugins:
  - serverless-deployment-bucket
  - serverless-localstack

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  region: ${opt:region, self:provider.region}
  configFile: ${file(./config/${self:custom.stage}.json)}
  serviceName: test-api
  priority: 180
  optionsOnly: false
  redirect: false
  localstack:
    # list of stages for which the plugin should be enabled
    stages:
      - dev
    host: http://localhost
    autostart: true  # optional - Start LocalStack in Docker on Serverless deploy
    #endpoints:
      # This section is optional - can be used for customizing the target endpoints
      #S3: http://localhost:4572
      #DynamoDB: http://localhost:4570
      #CloudFormation: http://localhost:4581
      #Elasticsearch: http://localhost:4571
      #ES: http://localhost:4578
      #SNS: http://localhost:4575
      #SQS: http://localhost:4576
      #Lambda: http://localhost:4574
      #Kinesis: http://localhost:4568
    debug: true
    lambda:
      mountCode: True # enable this flag for performance (True didn't work for me)
    docker:
      sudo: False # enable this flag to run "docker ..." commands as sudo
  stages:
    dev:
```

I keep getting

```
Running "serverless" from node_modules
Environment: darwin, node 18.2.0, framework 3.16.0 (local) 3.22.0v (global), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "custom.configFile": Value not found at "file" source
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with Serverless framework version 3.x. I downgraded my serverless framework version to 2.x and the error resolved itself.

'''
npm install -g serverless@2
'''

The following link may help in adhering to the new variable resolution method.

[Serverless Framework - Variables resolution error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807725/serverless-framework-variables-resolution-error)