# Serverless deployment fails with "Cannot resolve variable" error when inputs are used in Github composite action

Tags: github-actions, serverless

I have a Github composite action that uses the Serverless Framework to deploy my stack. The action takes two inputs, `serverless-path` and `stage`, and includes the following steps:

```
inputs:
  serverless-path:
    description: 'The relative path to the project root.'
    type: string
    required: true
  stage:
    description: 'The serverless deployment stage to use.'
    type: string
    required: true
    default: 'dev'
  otherArgs:
    description: 'Additional arguments to provide to the serverless deploy command.'
    type: string
    required: false
    default: ''

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '16.13.0'
        cache: yarn

    - name: Configure AWS Credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v2
      with:
        aws-region: us-east-1
        role-to-assume: *** 

    - name: Install project dependencies
      shell: bash
      run: yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      working-directory: ${{ inputs.serverless-path }}

    - name: debug step
      shell: bash
      run: yarn run serverless print --stage ${STAGE}
      working-directory: ${{ inputs.serverless-path }}
      env:
        STAGE: ${{ inputs.stage }}
```

However, when I run this action, the serverless command fails with the following error:

```
Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.SHOP": Value not found at "self" source
```

Interestingly, if I replace `${{ inputs.stage }}` with a static string like `dev`, the serverless command runs successfully. This makes me suspect that the problem has to do with how inputs are passed to the serverless command.

What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

Adding some additional debugging information. I tried a couple things to test that the value of `${{inputs.stage}}` is valid.

1. I simply did an `echo '${{ inputs.stage }}'` above the place where I run the command in the github action. Teh output looked correct:

```
Run echo 'dev​'
  echo 'dev​'
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  ...
dev​
```

2. I also tried an experiment commenting out the offending line with the nested variable expression in my serverless.yml, and then just added a few env definitions that pull the stage value in a number of ways:

```
provider: 
  ...
  environment:
    CUSTOM_STAGE: ${self:custom.stage}
    OPT_STAGE: ${opt:stage}
    SLS_STAGE: ${sls:stage}
    # SHOP: ${self:custom.environment.${self:custom.stage}.SHOP}
...
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'default'}
```

When I ran this, the `sls print` command actually executes without error, and the stage definnitions are all as expected, i.e. they pick up the `dev` value from `inputs.stage`:

```
provider:
  ...
  CUSTOM_STAGE: dev
  OPT_STAGE: dev
  SLS_STAGE: dev
```

So it seems as though the value is actually making it into the serverless variable resolution process, but somehow when nested variables are involved, and the value is taking from Github 's `inputs`, it blows up...

3. Lastly, I wanted to show more of the error output because what is interesting is that it looks like the value is being placed correctly on the command in the log:

```
Run yarn serverless print --stage ${STAGE}
  yarn serverless print --stage ${STAGE}
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    GITHUB_PKG_AUTH_TOKEN: ***
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_REGION: us-east-1
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ***
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ***
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: ***
    STAGE: dev​
yarn run v1.22.19
$ /home/runner/work/***/***/node_modules/.bin/serverless print --stage dev​
Environment: linux, node 16.13.0, framework 3.19.0 (local), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Error:
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.SHOP": Value not found at "self" source
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Note above the line called by yarn starting with `/home/runner...` has at it's end `--stage dev` just the way we'd expect. So why does this error out?

Comment: What is the value of `inputs.stage` that is passed? Is it also `dev`? Apparently, seems like a quoting issue i.e. `--stage "${STAGE}"`. Also, include the relevant inputs in your question.

Comment: @Azeem I added the inputs. inputs.stage is set by the call to the composite action, of course, but it can generally be dev, qa, or prod. Just strings. But the precise string really shouldn't matter, as any string should work. 

I would also have thought that it is a quoting issue, but I think I've tried every type of quoting, and then some, and nothing works. Also the github docs say that you do not have to quote strings: "You don't need to enclose strings in ${{ and }}....if you do... use single quotes (')."(https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions)

Comment: Yes, you should use single quote for those inputs. I was looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70807725/serverless-framework-variables-resolution-error) and it seems like the string may include colons e.g. `sls:stage` causing YAML syntax errors (if not properly handled). But, this is not the issue in your case. The first thing you should do is to check the value of the inputs and env vars being set using `echo '${{ inputs... }}'` or `echo "$ENV_VAR"` before using them in actual commands.

Comment: @Azeem I did try the echo to inspect the value doing `echo '${{ inputs.stage }}'` and the value is defined. I'll put the output above. Before testing this way, however, I'd also simply commented the `SHOP` line and set envs with just the stage in my serverless.yml, e.g. `SLS_STAGE: ${sls:stage}`. When I did that and ran `sls print` from the github action, then the command executed without error and those stage envs were defined correctly. So it seems it is picking up the value. But when I try to use the nested variable, the commands just fail.

Comment: "**But when I try to use the nested variable, the commands just fail.**", are you referring to this `SHOP: ${self:custom.environment.${self:custom.stage}.SHOP}`? Have you tested this locally? In your last output above, even when you set it to `dev`, the error is about `provider.environment.SHOP`, why is that? That doesn't seem to be nested.

Comment: @Azeem it works just fine locally. I only get these errors in the Github workflow context, and only when using an input within a composite action or a resusable workflow. The reference to `provider.environment.SHOP` is, I believe, referencing the property in the serverless config that it is failing to resolve for some reason.

Comment: Right. Yes, apparently it seems like something internal. If you could share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a repo, I'd be able to deep dive and iterate over on my side.

Comment: @Azeem thank you for all your attention to this. I'm working on a minimal repro repo right now.

Comment: @Azeem here I've reproduced the problem without the need for deployment, just using `sls print`: https://github.com/ezmiller/sls-resolve-failure. You can run the workflow "Deploy Something" and see it in action, or see the most recent run. If I run this locally, it works.

Comment: PR created (https://github.com/ezmiller/sls-resolve-failure/pull/1). Workflow issue is resolved (https://github.com/iamazeem/sls-resolve-failure/actions/runs/4805989745).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Azeem provided the solution: there was an "invisible" character of some sort in the workflow triggering the reusable workflow. I.e. see this diff:

```
@@ -23,6 +23,6 @@ jobs:
     uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-deploy-serverless.yml
     with:
       serverless-path: './packages/shopify-functions'
-      stage: ${{ matrix.stage }}
+      stage: ${{ matrix.stage }}
     secrets: inherit
```

Very hard to spot!